# Дескриптор окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

У меня возникла непредвиденная проблема: при вызове контролла компонента формы в потоке, точнее, есть основной поток, который вызывает backgroundworker, тот вызывает новый поток, и тот, в свою очередь, вызывает при необходимости последний поток, содержащий вызовы методов (потоки синхронизированы). В структуре одного из которых (методов) содержится запись:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>                           
    dataGridView2.Rows[
          Int32.Parse(SendMessage.ValueSendMessage.SendIndexUser[i, 0])
        ].Cells[2].Value = ""));
```

вызвав которую ловлю exception следящего содержания:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Вопрос следующий: форма же одна, и она уже создана, почему он говорит, что не может управлять элементом до завершения её создания?

P.S. 
Зато приведенный выше вызов  dataGridView2 прекрасно работает в backgroundworker.

Comment: Может быть, ваш `this` ещё не вставлен в основное окно?

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду, окно одно, классов 5

Comment: @SergD29: Ну например, контрол вы создали, но не добавили child'ом ни в какой другой контрол.

Или добавили в другой, а этот другой не добавили в окно. И т. д.

Comment: нет я подобного не использую, все наследование происходит через классы и перинициализацию в случай необходимости

Answer (score 1):

Invoke перебрасывает вызов не просто в какой-то "главный" поток. Он перебрасывает вызов именно в тот поток, в котором крутится цикл отрисовки нативного контола, обернутого в контрол WinForms. Т.е. для корректной работы ему нужен дескриптор (handle) нативного контрола.

Нативный контрол создается не в момент создания (вызова конструктора) формы, а (обычно) в момент ее отображения на экране.

Если ваш поток как-то обгоняет момент появления `this` (точнее, нативного контрола, который в этот `this` завернут) - Invoke будет выбрасывать именно эту ошибку. Т.е. нельзя создать форму, заполнить ее в *фоновом потоке*, а потом уже показать.

Вам нужно или дожидаться появления this (создания его handle) на экране. И откладывать любые Invoke до момента, пока `IsHandleCreated` станет равным `true`.

**Или**

просто использовать проверку на `InvokeRequired`. Система с `Invoke` создана для того, чтобы избежать трудноуловимых багов при изменении данных в одном потоке, в момент отрисовки контрола в другом потоке. Нет handle - нет цикла отрисовки - `InvokeRequired` вернет `false` - эта проверка + проверка на совпадение потоков - и есть [суть его стандартной реализации](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,d3ab1956c1b4c3db):

```
var action = new Action(() =>                           
    dataGridView2.Rows[
          Int32.Parse(SendMessage.ValueSendMessage.SendIndexUser[i, 0])
        ].Cells[2].Value = "");

if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(action);
}
else
{
    action();
}
```